# how to compare the code present in eclipse work space with the code present in the svn repository using eclipse adt

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

i am having  a project in my adt eclipse project explorer and i want  to compare this code with the code which is present in the svn repository..

I am using Adt Eclipse,subclipse plugin is installed in eclipse!!

How to do the above process 
help me

Answer (score 1):

```
Right click on the project-->Compare with-->Latest From repository
```

or

press `Ctrl+Alt+L`

Comment: your project not sync with svn.sync your project with svn first

Comment: i want to compare the modified project with the previous project in  svn...its showing there are no differences with the selected inputs